# Sliding UIView between 2 fixed points

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, touch, slide

I'm trying to let a UIView slide between 2 points on slide touch. I've tried using UIPanGestureRecognizer. The sliding is fine but when the view arrive at the limit point, there's a bumpy jump. It's not smooth. This is my gesture function:

```
    func wasDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        print(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x)
        if(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x <= self.view.frame.width) && (gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x >= self.view.frame.width - 100) {
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y:  gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }else if (gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x > self.view.frame.width){
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }else if (gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x < self.view.frame.width - 100){
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 100, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }

        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), in: self.view)
    }


}
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Your code is extremely questionable. It could be written far more neatly and compactly by using a few intermediate local variable. You should not be setting `center`, a point, in terms of `width`, a length. And why is your third `else if` testing whether the center x is _less_ than width minus 100? Of course you will then jump to width minus 100! That is what your code says to do.

Comment: Okay the y is fixed. I'm moving the customView between 2 points with coordinates: the width of the initial view, and this width -100.

Comment: "The width of the initial view" is not a point, not a coordinate. It is a length.

Comment: The width is a value which can be used as a x coordinate. Anyways, the problem is not here. I've tried setting normal coordinate but the problem persists. When the custom view arrive to the boundary, it's jumping back a little bit. I don't want it to jump back. I want it to be smooth. I hope you understand what i mean...

Comment: Okay, let's concentrate on the jump. Suppose I move the view quickly to `width-105`. You then immediately set it to `width-100`. That is a jump! I don't see what the surprise is here.

Comment: Yes i know. I understand where the jump comes from but how can i avoid it? Not let it arrive to width - 105 following your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are looking at where the view is now, and not where it will be after the current move has been applied.

I fixed your code by introducing `newx` which shows where the view is trying to move to.  That is the value that you want to constrain.

```
@IBAction func wasDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        print(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x)
        let newx = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x

        if(newx <= self.view.frame.width) && (newx >= self.view.frame.width - 100) {
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: newx, y:  gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }else if (newx > self.view.frame.width){
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }else if (newx < self.view.frame.width - 100){
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 100, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }

        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), in: self.view)
    }
}
```

---

You might also want to consider a change to your final `setTranslation` call.  If the user tries to drag the view left when it is already at its left limit and then (without lifting their finger) changes direction and moves to the right, your code will move the view right even though their finger is no longer over the view.

With the change below, the view will not move to the right until the user's finger gets back to the original touch point:

```
gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: newx - gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x ,y: 0), in: self.view)
```

Try it and see which you prefer.

Comment: I updated the answer to add a suggestion about your final `setTranslation` call.  Take a look.